# "Constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type" when defining streams in Scala

Tags: scala

I tried to implement a StreamInt (without using generic types) and got an error message from REPL

```
<console>:29: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Cons
 required: StreamInt.type
             case Cons(hd,tl)=> if (n==0) hd else tl().nth(n-1)
```

The code is pasted below. Anyone can show me how to get it right?

```
  trait StreamInt
  case object Empty extends StreamInt
  case class Cons (hd: Int, tl: ()=>StreamInt) extends StreamInt


  object StreamInt{
    def cons(hd:Int, tl: => StreamInt):StreamInt = {
      val head=hd
      lazy val tail=tl
      Cons(head, ()=>tail)
    }
    def empty:StreamInt = Empty

    def apply(as: Int*):StreamInt={
      if (as.isEmpty) empty
      else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
    }

    def nth(n:Int):Int= this match {
      case Cons(hd,tl)=> if (n==0) hd else tl().nth(n-1)
      case _ => throw new Exception("out of bound!")

    }

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this match {

That line means you are matching the **containing object**, in your case that is `object StreamInt`. That (companion) *object* can never be a `Cons` cell. You probably want to have the method `nth` on the *class* or *trait* `StreamInt`:

```
sealed trait StreamInt {
  def nth(n:Int):Int= this match {
    case Cons(hd,tl)=> if (n==0) hd else tl().nth(n-1)
    case Empty => throw new Exception("out of bound!")
  }
}
case object Empty extends StreamInt
case class Cons (hd: Int, tl: ()=>StreamInt) extends StreamInt

object StreamInt{
  def cons(hd:Int, tl: => StreamInt):StreamInt = {
    val head=hd
    lazy val tail=tl
    Cons(head, ()=>tail)
  }
  def empty:StreamInt = Empty

  def apply(as: Int*):StreamInt={
    if (as.isEmpty) empty
    else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
  }
}
```

Now `this` refers to the `trait StreamInt` which may indeed by a `Con` or `Empty`.

I also added the `sealed` modifier, that ensures that the compiler can warn you if you miss a particular case when using pattern matching.

Comment: I still got erros with yours, by pasting it to REPL:  <console>:16: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Cons[A]
 required: StreamInt
           case Cons(hd,tl)=> if (n==0) hd else tl().nth(n-1)
                ^
<console>:17: error: pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
 found   : Empty.type
 required: StreamInt
           case Empty => throw new Exception("out of bound!")
                ^

Comment: Must be a problem of pasting; are you sure you are pasting the entire code en-bloc? See https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-repl-how-to-paste-load-blocks-of-source-code